# Is there a way to immediately block a pthread after creating it?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

Basically, I just want to create a pthread for each number of threads available on the machine, without doing any work. I want to somehow block each one at the start and add it to a threadpool so I can pull an available pthread from the pool when I need work to be done.

How do I go about blocking without having a pthread doing any work? I've tried a dummy function but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have it start off by waiting on the work queue. This would normally involve `pthread_cond_wait` or `sem_wait` or similar depending on what type of synchronization primitives you're using to manage the work queue.